# Javascript Show/Hide text

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, show-hide

I'm trying to have a list in which when a user clicks, an image shows up along with a text under it. Let's say for List 1, I want it to say "Price: $1" when the link is clicked. And then for List 2, "Price: $2" under the image when the link is clicked. The same functions as the image show/hide ideally. Then when clicked away, hides the elements. I'm fairly new to JS but here's what I've gathered so far:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".imgPreview").hide();
  $(".unstyled li a").click(function () {
    $(".imgPreview").show().find("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));

    return false;
  });
  $("body").click(function () {
    $(".imgPreview").hide();

  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
body {margin: 10px;}
li {margin: 25px;}
.unstyled, .imgPreview, .showPrice {float: left; width: 50%;}
.unstyled, .imgPreview img {max-width: 100%;}
p {margin: 5px;}

.recycle-button {
    padding: 6px 6px;
    background-color: rgb(53, 189, 208);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-bottom: 35px;">
<h3>LIST</h3> </div>
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 6</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="imgPreview">
  <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="150"/>
</div>
```

My goal is to have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN6Od.jpg).

Edit:

So far, I've tried adding the attribute *data-price* to the element *<a* to hold the price data:

```
<li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button" data-price="Price: $3.20">List 1</a></li>
```

and have the script do the same function with the imgPreview:

```
$(".imgPreview").show().find("p").attr($(this).attr("data-price"));
```

I'm [fiddling](https://jsfiddle.net/xfcn7sz4/) with this and the error I get is "Script error." Surely, you can see the limited knowledge I have with JS.

Comment: Could you be more explicit in what you've tried, where and what errors are you getting (if there are).

Comment: @cape_bsas Absolutely. Thanks for your comment on clarification. Fairly new to the community so bare with me. Check edit on post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want something like this...

```js
$(function () {
  $(".imgPreview").hide();
  $(".unstyled li a").click(function (event) {
    var listItem = event.target.parentElement;
    var image = $(".imgPreview");
    image.show();
    image.find("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    $(image.find("span"))[0].innerHTML="Price = $"+ ($( "li" ).index( listItem ) + 1);
    return false;
  });
  $("body").click(function () {
    $(".imgPreview").hide();

  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
body {margin: 10px;}
li {margin: 25px;}
.unstyled, .imgPreview, .showPrice {float: left; width: 50%;}
.unstyled, .imgPreview img {max-width: 100%;}
p {margin: 5px;}

.recycle-button {
    padding: 6px 6px;
    background-color: rgb(53, 189, 208);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-bottom: 35px;">
<h3>LIST</h3> </div>
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="recycle-button">List 6</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="imgPreview">
  <img src="" alt="" width="350" height="150"/>
  <span id="priceView"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is helpful but the price goes up in increments. How can I set custom prices for different list items? e.g. List 1: Price = $13.24, List 4: Price = $3.02.

Comment: @abarkez, for that you must change the below line to suit your requirement.
$(image.find("span"))[0].innerHTML="Price = $"+ calculatePrice();
This calculatePrice will be a method that will calculate and return you the prices.